# Rails - What does the staged? function do

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, file-upload, paperclip

I've tried looking through the documentation to find the source code or a description of what this function does exactly. I'm currently using Paperclip to upload files to my rails app and am trying to persist an uploaded file if the form fails on validation.

In examples of other's code, I've seen them use this function when referring to a file.
I assume this is to check if a file is waiting to be uploaded to the application but I dont like using functions that I dont fully understand.

Appreciate any response.

Edit * Code that uses .staged?

```
Class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base    
  attr_accessor :logo_cache

  has_attached_file :logo

  def cache_images
    if logo.staged? # This is where I'm not exactly sure what happens
      if invalid?
        FileUtils.cp(logo.queued_for_write[:original].path, logo.path(:original))
        @logo_cache = encrypt(logo.path(:original))
      end
    else
      if @logo_cache.present?
        File.open(decrypt(@logo_cache)) {|f| assign_attributes(logo: f)}
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is [defined in *lib/paperclip/attachment.rb*](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb#L178). It represents a property of *@queued_for_write* (if it is not empty). This attribute contains a queue of temporary files, which have not yet been written to the destination they are supposed to end up.

What your code basically does is, check if the upload has not yet been written to its final destination, and if this is the case, copy it to the final destination (Paperclip would do that on save anyway). Then the path to the original file is encrypted(by whatever method...) and saved in *@logo_cache*.

If the image is not staged (so something which is already saved, or was not even uploaded) it decrypts the filename in *@logo_cache* and assigns attributes to the original image (again this is something Paperclip does automatically).

Besides that I do not understand much of this method either without proper context. I would not consider it especially elegant to replicate functionality, which is (/should) be encapsuled in Paperclip itself. Why the method encrypts and decrypts, based on the current status of the file, and only in one case actually updates the "cache" (whatever that is) and only in one case updates the attributes, remains completely in the dark to me.

Comment: Thankyou for answering in such detail. I don't quite understand why the method was written the way it was either. But it was one I came across when looking for how to persist a file upload if the form fails on validation, saving the user from having to reattach files.